# Management of authorizations and access permissions

Tags: linux, windows, permissions, user-accounts, microsoft-account

In our company, we use several systems, all unrelated to each other. For example, we use online systems like a CRM system, a PasswordManager, Microsoft 365, but also internal systems like a NAS, and a support ticket system. (Note: we don't use a directory, like AD)

Our employees have access to most of these systems with accounts that are made on those systems. Each employee can have different roles that have different permissions. What is becoming troublesome is the bookkeeping: who has access to what? It's now registered in an Excel file (of course).

So my question is: is there a software package or commands already present in the OS, that allows me to keep an administration of systems, it's users and their roles? It's not supposed to interrogate the systems, it needs to make the administration a easier for me.

A broader question would be: how do you keep track of all the user, groups, roles and permissions over different systems?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: When you face the problem from this direction, the outcome is always the same. Manual work. Instead of keeping track of all permissions etc, you want to set everything up in one system and make it change all permissions elsewhere. Active Directory or even Microsoft Azure AD would be ideal for this. Once this exists, other systems can be synced with it.

Answer (score 1):

You may create a database for this... or simply go forward with excel but...

1. Keep one master document with the list of all users and their unique key.
2. Keep single pages/document for each service but do not allow to add user not present in the master document of point 1. Report the unique key in this document too.
3. Create for each user a summary going to search for the unique key in the single-service documents.

A database we said...
and however backup always.

Note that the user and group level access mechanism on *nix systems was designed to handle such situations. Your case is broader but the philosophy is similar.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to "manage" this is to use Excel, (Access, ...) and create long-winded lists. This is a very bad idea and ultimately bound to fail, no matter what:

Documentation (what you want is basically that, you want to know what is going on) should generate itself or at least be *generatable* from the actual data: if you, say, transmit files and you use a list of some sort (Excel or otherwise) where you note down all transmitted files, chances are you will, one day or another, forget to write the transmitted file down, rendering your list wrong (and ultimately useless). Or write down an entry and forget to transmit the file. Errors will accumulate because transmitting the file and writing an entry to your list are two distinct activities and have nothing directly to do with each other. Now, imagine starting over with a new, empty Excel sheet: how long would it take to retrieve every necessary entry and for how long will this new list remain accurate?

On the other hand, if you make moving the transmitted file to some directory part of the process the "list" builds itself, can always be reproduced (do a `ls`, `dir`, etc.) and will always be accurate.

Having said this: use a **directory service** of some sort, because there you can always create a list of active permissions from its database and hence will always have accurate information. You can use Active Directory, but that is basically a dumbed-down LDAP with a fixed (and not very elaborate) structure using Kerberos V as authentication mechanism.

Create an LDAP domain yourself and you will get a lot more mileage out of it, although to come up with a structure tailored to your needs will be some non-trivial design task. My suggestion is to get external help from an LDAP expert to set that up because chances are you won't get it right the first (or even the second) time.